# Error when running Xcode simulator - '[framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager, xcode10

I am developing an app with a single view and some labels. The app fails at the viewdidload() func and does not proceed further. The code is listed below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

The error is **'[framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0'**

I am not using any themes or external frameworks in my code. I am running Xcode 10 on MacOS Mojave. I checked the setting in Xcode to see if it is referring to any external frameworks and I could not find any. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am seeing this message in the debug log too - [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0, but the app works fine for me - no observable issues except this odd log message. If I figure it out I will post an answer.

Comment: I figured it out. This error can be resolved by moving the image files to Assets.xcassets folder in Xcode. I had my image files in a different folder and moved them to Assets folder.

Comment: @ spenumatsa is right, I moved all my images to Assets folder. Warning gone.

Comment: If you figured it out by yourself, please add the solution [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding it as a comment. This will help future readers. You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so.

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same issue.

Simply move your image(s) to `Assets.xcassets` folder.

Comment: Also to note, I found that when I pull in cocoapods, I have no control to clear this error. The images are build into the framework and cannot be moved out.

Comment: Is the error solved by moving the images into an "Asset Catalog" (of any name) or does it have to be `Assets.xcassets`.

My project is using `Media.xcassets` (which I think is the new default-name.

Comment: Strange...but this one worked for me! The error message in console is not enough descriptive to highlight that there is issue with image assets.

Comment: To make it even more strange: as [this](https://medium.com/@GoalStack/cuithemestore-no-theme-registered-with-id-0-a19ef2a95a56) Medium post says, you can just drop a random image from your desktop into the asset catalog, run the app once, delete the image again and it should be solved. In my case that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It took place because I messed up with window property in the AppDelegate class.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let mainScreen = TaskNumber1()
        mainScreen.title = "Task nunber 1"

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainScreen)

        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

I've just created new window property and there was not any warnings from Xcode that I tried to create the constant with the same name as one was created already. But I had just black screen and the same error as you. So in my case solution was simple. To replace that window code snippet with the code below:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Now I am simply not creating new window variable.

**In my case, there was nothing to do with themes. So the reason of you getting this error is could be in AppDelegate class as well.** Hope it will help somebody