# CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0 on Watch Extension on device

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

When I try to execute my app on my Watch I get

> AppExtension [framework]: CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0

while the code rests on

> lybsystem_platform_dlyb'_platform_memmove at line 23.

No error comes out instead when I execute the app on the simulator. The error seems to pop up between **applicationDidFinishLaunching()** and **ApplicationDidBecomeActive()**.
If I try to have the execution progress, it ends for the better with:

> Terminated due to memory issue.

I use Xcode10.1 with an iPhone XS with iOS 12.1 and watchOS 5.1.1.

How may I know better and fix the issue?

Comment: I'm running into the same item in my log on a react native based project on iPhone and iPad.  Mine results in a white screen after the launch image goes away, but the home page still works (other than being all white).  This ONLY happens in release scheme.  If I change the scheme to debug, the issue goes away.  Have you solved this @Fabrizio Bartolomucci?

Comment: I'm not sure the white screen is a result of this error or vice versa, or if they're related at all btw.

Comment: I have a Photo Editing Extension that was working at one time, but now is giving me the same error. For me it was related to accidentally removing an Media.assets library I had to create to have the extension work. While this probably *isn't* your issue, I was reminded of this while reading this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860566/error-when-running-xcode-simulator-framework-cuithemestore-no-theme-regist

Comment: No way, I submitted the app as it is hoping the clients won't experience the problem.